# Move message to another folder with graphClient 5.18

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I need to move (some filtered) messages between folders at specified users with Microsoft Graph Api 5.18.

- I created the API in Azure AD with the required permissions.

  - Mail.Read (Delegated)
  - Mail.ReadBasic (Delegated)
  - Mail.ReadWrite (Delegated)
  - User.Read (Delegated)
  - User.Read.All (Delegated)
  - User.ReadBasic.All (Delegated)
- I can access the logged in user's messages and folders. (Delegated permission is working fine.)

The API documentation give an example with the Messages of the authenticated user (`.Me`).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

`C#`

```
// Code snippets are only available for the latest version. Current version is 5.x

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Me.Messages.Item.Move.MovePostRequestBody
{
    DestinationId = "deleteditems",
};
var result = await graphClient.Me.Messages["{message-id}"].Move.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

It is possible to configure the user id with CLI:

`CLI`

```
mgc users messages move post --user-id {user-id} --message-id {message-id} --body '{\
  "destinationId": "deleteditems"\
}\
'
```

**How can I define the 'user id' instead of 'Me' in C#?**

I'd like to make similar than this (specify the 'user id' with 'ArchiveUser.Id'):

```
var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users[ArchiveUser.Id].Messages.Item.Move.MovePostRequestBody
{
DestinationId = "deleteditems",
};
var result2 = await graphClient.Users[ArchiveUser.Id].Messages[item.Id].Move.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

UPDATE:
What does the correct requestBody2 parameter look like for the following PostAsync parameter? I'd like to use another user id (ArchiveUser.Id) to move his messages.
[image]

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/main/api-reference/v1.0/api/message-move.md

Comment: It's not clear what's the issue but you want to use graphClient.Users[{user_id}].Messages[{message_id}].Move.PostAsync(requestBody) where {user_id} is the id of the signed-in user?

Comment: @user2250152 I took a screenshot and put it at the end of the question for clarification. I want to move the messages of another user, not the logged-in (delegated) user. The problem is that I can't create a correct requestBody parameter. (Example: Logged in user: User1. Need to move some message within User2\inbox folder to User2\Archive2022 folder).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. It's more clear now. Will see whether you can access messages of another user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `MovePostRequestBody` is in the namespace `Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.Messages.Item.Move`, so create the request body like this:

```
try
{
    var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.Messages.Item.Move.MovePostRequestBody
    {
        DestinationId = "{destination_mailbox_folder_id}",
    };
    var result2 = await graphClient.Users[ArchiveUser.Id].Messages[item.Id].Move.PostAsync(requestBody);
}
catch (ODataError ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Error.Message);
}
```